# How to accept changes made in the master branch to a database, that you have already deployed in local using Sqitch?

Tags: database, sqitch

I deployed a DB using the plan file that was in my branch(reports). My boss has made some changes to the master branch. I need to test the said changes that were made to master. My local is outdated, as I pulled all the changes in the master into my local machine. I tried the following while in the master branch.

```
fifthgear % sqitch deploy fifthgear
Nothing to deploy (up-to-date)
```

Then I tried;

```
fifthgear % sqitch revert fifthgear
Revert all changes from fifthgear? [Yes] Yes
Change "sales_data" required by currently deployed change: adi-etl-swtraders:sales_data@v1.0.0
Change "sales_purchasing_data" required by currently deployed change: adi-etl-swtraders:purchasing_data@v1.0.0
Change "sales_data_customers" required by currently deployed change: adi-etl-swtraders:customers@v1.0.0.....
```

after which I tired;

```
fifthgear % sqitch rebase fifthgear
Revert all changes from fifthgear? [Yes] yes
Change "sales_data" required by currently deployed change: adi-etl-swtraders:sales_data@v1.0.0
Change "sales_purchasing_data" required by currently deployed change: adi-etl-swtraders:purchasing_data@v1.0.0
Change "sales_data_customers" required by currently deployed change: adi-etl-swtraders:customers@v1.0.0......
```

It seems to me that there are dependent databases that rely on this main database, that prevent me from rebasing or revert fifthgear. How would one go about accepting new changes that were made in a different branch?

Additionally, would

```
sqitch rework fifthgear
```

be a useful option in this scenario.